# TSQL Query column which is true if condition is met within "chain" of rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sorting, calculated-columns

This is a follow-up from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59459397/performing-an-operation-on-the-result-of-a-query-without-saving-a-table/59459643#59459643). This is going to get complicated.

I have a table like the following for tracking the start and end of incidents of a specific type:

```
+----------+-------------+------------------+------------------+
| PersonID | Weapon Used |     StartDate    |     EndDate      |
+----------+-------------|------------------+------------------+
|      006 | Knife       | 2019-12-01 09:30 | 2019-12-02 06:15 |
|      007 | Grenade     | 2019-12-01 12:15 | 2019-12-01 12:16 |
|      006 | Bat         | 2019-12-02 06:15 | 2019-12-02 15:15 |
|      006 | Pistol      | 2019-12-02 15:15 | 2019-12-02 23:01 |
|      007 | Pistol      | 2019-12-02 07:23 | 2019-12-04 08:30 |
+----------+-------------+------------------+------------------+
```

I'm trying to create a calculated column that returns TRUE under the following conditions:

- The row event is a part of a "chain" of 1+ back to back events.
- **AND** The pistol is used 1+ times within the chain of events.
- **AND** The row event has the earliest StartDate within the chain.

Creating a table like this:

```
+----------+-------------+------------------+------------------+---------+
| PersonID | Weapon Used |     StartDate    |     EndDate      | Pistol+ |
+----------+-------------|------------------+------------------+---------+
|      006 | Knife       | 2019-12-01 09:30 | 2019-12-02 06:15 | TRUE    |
|      007 | Grenade     | 2019-12-01 12:15 | 2019-12-01 12:16 | FALSE   |
|      006 | Bat         | 2019-12-02 06:15 | 2019-12-02 15:15 | FALSE   |
|      006 | Pistol      | 2019-12-02 15:15 | 2019-12-02 23:01 | FALSE   |
|      007 | Pistol      | 2019-12-02 07:23 | 2019-12-04 08:30 | TRUE    |
+----------+-------------+------------------+------------------+---------+
```

It's admittedly a tall order, but one I have to do for a large amount of rows, so I'm desperately trying to avoid having to calculate it by hand and eyeball. Is this possible?

Comment: Why the row with Grenade has result FALSE?

Comment: It's not a part of a back to back event chain with 007's pistol event.

Comment: You have to explain better what you mean by back to back event.

Comment: If an event has the same start date as another event's enddate, with the same personID, they're back to back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will required `recursive cte` to find the `grp` of related back-to-back rows

`seq` is to identify the first of the `group`

to identify if the group contains `pistol`, it uses window function `sum()` with conditional `case`

```
with
cte as
(
    select  *, rn = row_number() over (partition by PersonID order by StartDate)
    from    yourtable
),
rcte as
(
    select  c.PersonID, c.[Weapon Used], c.StartDate, c.EndDate, c.rn, 
            grp = 1, seq = 1
    from    cte c
    where   rn  = 1

    union all

    select  c.PersonID, c.[Weapon Used], c.StartDate, c.EndDate, c.rn,
            grp   = case    when    r.EndDate = c.StartDate
                            then    r.grp
                            else    r.grp + 1
                            end,
            seq   = case    when    r.EndDate = c.StartDate
                            then    r.seq + 1
                            else    1
                            end
    from    cte c
            inner join rcte r   on  c.PersonID  = r.PersonID
                               and  c.rn        = r.rn + 1
)
select  *,
        case    when    seq = 1
                and     sum(case when [Weapon Used] = 'Pistol' then 1 else 0 end) 
                        over (partition by PersonID, grp) >= 1
                then    'TRUE'
                else    'FALSE'
                end
from    rcte;
```